# How to change case of an NSMutableAttributedString in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uppercase, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a `NSMutableAttributedString` that contain values in lower case letters. I need to convert all the lowercase letters to uppercase. We can solve this using `uppercaseString` for normal string as:

```
[string uppercaseString];
```

How can I change my case for `NSMutableAttributedString`? Thanks!

Comment: When is set the string in your attributed string? You may want to do the upper case before that moment.

Comment: yes..actually i am getting string value from server as lower case so before setting the text, i need to change case of NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: For those who seek a solution that preserves the attributes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716699/how-to-change-characters-case-to-upper-in-nsattributedstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableAttributedString` class doesn't have `uppercaseString` method. So you can use like this..

```
NSString *str = @"objective-c";

str = [str uppercaseString];

NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
NSLog(@"Attributed String %@",attStr);
```

And You wanna upper latter in particular range then do something like this...

```
[attStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@"O"];
```

Comment: great! best way to do it like this.. Thanks @Dharmbir

Comment: yeah sure.. but i can accept answer after two minutes only :(

Answer (score 3):

Hope the below code snippet may help you

```
NSMutableAttributedString * linkString = [[NSMutableAttributedString  alloc]initWithString:@"Google"];

NSString * strings = [[linkString string]uppercaseString];

[linkString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [linkString length]) withString:strings];

NSLog(@"UpperCase   %@",linkString);
```